# locale param not changing language of returned address

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get info about event using Facebook GraphQL API but it seems that the documented `locale` param is not making any impact - no matter what i'm gonna put in it, i'm always getting a city and country names of event place in english language.

Debug info below:

```
==== Query
  curl -i -X GET \
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/1971053086509548?fields=place&locale=de_DE&access_token=<access token sanitized>"
==== Access Token Info
  {
    "perms": [
      "user_birthday",
      "user_relationship_details",
      "user_photos",
      "user_friends",
      "manage_pages",
      "pages_show_list",
      "business_management",
      "public_profile",
      "basic_info"
    ],
    "user_id": 584562931,
    "app_id": 145634995501895
  }
==== Parameters
- Query Parameters

  {
    "fields": "place",
    "locale": "de_DE"
  }
- POST Parameters

  {}
==== Response
  {
    "place": {
      "name": "Pogłos",
      "location": {
        "city": "Warsaw",
        "country": "Poland",
        "latitude": 52.25494,
        "longitude": 20.97925,
        "street": "Burakowska 12"
      },
      "id": "1591050677890570"
    },
    "id": "1971053086509548",
    "__debug__": {}
  }
==== Debug Information from Graph API Explorer
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=1971053086509548%3Ffields%3Dplace%26locale%3Dde_DE&version=v2.11
```

Comment: It simply doesn’t work for locations.

Comment: @CBroe isn't graphql what official facebook apps are using for fetching data? I can see everything localized fine in the web/mobile app